# Prolog - Most common occurring sequence of length N in a list

Tags: list, prolog, logic, sequence

I am trying to find the most common sequence of length N that occurs in a list. So I am supposed to write a predicate common(L,N,X) that gives me this sequence in a form of a list. For example: `common([1,2,3,2,3,1,4],2,X)` should give me back `X=[2,3]` ; `common([1,2,3,4,2,2,2,3,4],3,X)` should give back `X=[2,3,4]` or `common([1,2,3],1,X)` should give `X=[1] X=[2] X=[3]`.

I have read a couple of posts when we seek only the most common element (so a case where N=1), but I don`t know how to do it for a general N. I am not allowed to use if-then-else or clpfd.

I was thinking maybe grouping the elements and then ordering them, so for `common([1,2,3,2,3,1,4],2,X)` make a list like this`[[1,2],[2,3],[3,2],[2,3],[3,1],[1,4]]` and then order the elements from most common to least.

Answer (score 2):

I like your plan. Here's how I'd get the overlapping subsequences.

First, let's get the prefix of the list of length N:

```
subsequences(L, N, Sub) :- append(Sub, _, L), length(Sub, N).
```

This should be read "Sub is a subsequence of length N of list L if Sub, appended to something else yields L, and the length of Sub is N." This will definitely get you a prefix of L of length N. Now let's see the recursive case:

```
subsequences([_|L], N, Sub) :- subsequences(L, N, Sub).
```

"Otherwise, find a subsequence in the tail of L." And this will produce multiple solutions:

```
?- subsequences([1,2,3,2,3,1,4], 2, X).
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [2, 3] ;
X = [3, 2] ;
X = [2, 3] ;
X = [3, 1] ;
X = [1, 4] ;
```

`findall/3` is your friend here, you can use it to build the list you want:

```
?- findall(X, subsequences([1,2,3,2,3,1,4], 2, X), Subsequences).
Subsequences = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 4]].
```

Hope this helps!